# Java & Ghostscript (ghost4j and gsdll32.dll)

Tags: java, swing, ghostscript, ghost4j

I have a project in which I use: ghost4j (0.3.3) and gsdll32.dll.

But new Operation System (Win 10) are 64 and Swing Application (Java 1.6) return error Unable to load library 'gsdll32'.

I downloaded file gsdll64 and if I changed the name to gsdll32 everything works properly.
Notwithstanding, I want to use file with right name (gsdll64).

I tried to change version of ghost4j, unfortunately it still evokes gsdll32.

P.S. Sorry for my English

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a 32/64-bit problem. Presumably previously you were using a 32-bit OS and 32-bit Java etc.

Now you are using a 64-bit Java which needs a 64-bit DLL (presumably because it is itself 64-bit). But whatever framework you are using has a fixed name and is looking for the 32-bit library. If you want to fix that you'll need to change whatever it is that has the fixed name, presumably ghost4j.

This isn't a Ghostscript question and I can't tell you how to change Ghost4j I'm afraid. You could use a 32-bit Java installation or, as you've already done, simply rename the DLL.